# How to pass non-static class member to callback?

Tags: esp8266, c++

I am using the [arduinoWebSockets](https://github.com/Links2004/arduinoWebSockets/) library in my own Arduino library. I'm having trouble with trying to assign a class member as the websocket library `onEvent` callback function.

MyClass.cpp:

```
#include <WebSocketsClient.h>
#include "Arduino.h"
#include "MyClass.h"

void MyClass::connect(String host, int port) {
  webSocket.begin(host, port, "/");
  webSocket.setReconnectInterval(5000);

  // tried all these variations
  // webSocket.onEvent(incomingEventHandler);
  // webSocket.onEvent(MyClass::incomingEventHandler);
  webSocket.onEvent(this->incomingEventHandler);
}

void MyClass::loop() {
  webSocket.loop();
}

void MyClass::incomingEventHandler(WStype_t type, uint8_t *payload, size_t length) {
  // do stuff with incoming data
  // need to access other member functions and class variables
}
```

MyClass.h:

```
#ifndef MyClass_h
#define MyClass_h

#include <WebSocketsClient.h>
#include "Arduino.h"

class MyClass {
  public:
    void connect(String host, int port);
    void loop();
    void incomingEventHandler(WStype_t type, uint8_t *payload, size_t length);
  private:
    WebSocketsClient webSocket;
};

#endif
```

The error returned is:

> sketch/MyClass.cpp: In member function 'void MyClass::connect(String,
>   int)': MyClass.cpp:14:47: error: no matching function for call to
>   'WebSocketsClient::onEvent()'
>   webSocket.onEvent(this->incomingEventHandler);

---

From what I understand it seems like I need to create a pointer to the class member, I have tried a few different ways, this one seemed the most promising, but still failed:

```
typedef void (MyClass::*MyClassMemFn)(WStype_t type, uint8_t *payload, size_t length);

void MyClass::connect(String host, int port) {
  webSocket.begin(host, port, "/");
  webSocket.setReconnectInterval(5000);

  MyClassMemFn onEventCallback = &MyClass::incomingEventHandler;
  webSocket.onEvent(MyClassMemFn onEventCallback);
}
```

The above returns this error:

> sketch/MyClass.cpp: In member function 'void MyClass::connect(String,
>   int)': MyClass.cpp:15:34: error: expected primary-expression before
>   'onEventCallback'    webSocket.onEvent(MyClassMemFn onEventCallback);

---

I have also tried to use `std::bind`:

```
void MyClass::connect(String host, int port) {
  webSocket.begin(host, port, "/");
  webSocket.setReconnectInterval(5000);

  webSocket.onEvent(std::bind(&MyClass::incomingEventHandler, this));
}
```

Error:

> sketch/MyClass.cpp: In member function 'void MyClass::connect(String,
>   int)': MyClass.cpp:12:47: error: no matching function for call to
>   'WebSocketsClient::onEvent()'
>   webSocket.onEvent(this->incomingEventHandler);

---

If I move the `incomingEventHandler` function outside the class definition, it works as expected, however then I can't call other class members or access class properties in the same scope.

In arduino c++ how can I pass non-static class member properties as a callback? Is there a better way to approach this?

Comment: @asked This is actually a question about how C++ works. The magic is in the handling of `this`. Member functions have a "hidden" parameter. `This` is necessary to allow access to the member data and virtual function table. The short answer to your question is therefore - a callback cannot be a member function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, a callback can be a member function. The error in your `std::bind` call is that while you do bind the first hidden `this` paramater to an object instance, in this case `this` object, you must also use placeholders for all your other function parameters.

Since you declared

```
void incomingEventHandler(WStype_t type, uint8_t *payload, size_t length)
```

You must bind as

```
webSocket.onEvent(std::bind(&MyClass::incomingEventHandler, this,  std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2, std::placeholders::_3));
```

Note that this `webSocket.onEvent` call only works if you are on a non-AVR platform, because the library defines

```
void WebSocketsClient::onEvent(WebSocketClientEvent cbEvent) {
    _cbEvent = cbEvent;
}
```

with

```
#ifdef __AVR__
        typedef void (*WebSocketClientEvent)(WStype_t type, uint8_t * payload, size_t length);
#else
        typedef std::function<void (WStype_t type, uint8_t * payload, size_t length)> WebSocketClientEvent;
#endif
```

i.e., it is a raw function pointer in `__AVR__` but a `std::function` on non-AVR platforms -- `std::bind` will give you a `std::function`. Since you're on an ESP8266, this should work fine.

Refer to https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind (and maybe [my old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50413872/c17-cannot-use-stdbind-to-produce-a-stdfunction))