# Passing non-static member function using bind

Tags: c++, esp32, callbacks

I'm using the [GxEPD2 library](https://github.com/ZinggJM/GxEPD2/tree/master/src) to communicate with an E-Paper display. I now wanted to use the `drawPaged` method of this library with an object `display`.

I also have written my own class from which I want to print stuff on the display.

Here's the relevant code for the MyClass.h:

```
class MyClass{
    //some variables and methods
    void drawClass(); //this is public
    void drawClassCallback(const void* v1); //this is private
    //    this is actually a uint8_t --^
}
```

And here's the MyClass.cpp:

```
void MyClass::drawClass(){
    //some display preparation
    uint8_t var; //A variable to pass information from the callback to this method since it is needed later
    display.drawPaged(std::bind(&MyClass::drawClassCallback, this, &var));
    //some code where I need var with info from the callback
}
```

I'm getting the following error:

> no matching function for call to 'GxEPD2_BW::drawPaged(std::_Bind_helper::type)'
>
> note: candidate: void GxEPD2_BW::drawPaged(void (*)(const void*), const void*) [with GxEPD2_Type = GxEPD2_290; short unsigned int page_height = 296u]
>        void drawPaged(void (*drawCallback)(const void*), const void* pv)

I've also tried `display.drawPaged(std::bind(&MyClass::drawClassCallback, this, std::placeholders::_1), &var)` without success.

I've stumbled upon [this post](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/56026/how-to-pass-non-static-class-member-to-callback) already, however the solution presented there (and the one used above) does not work in this case.

Why is that?

Answer (score 1):

In your `MyClass` example, the `drawPaged()` call is given only a single argument, while according to the library, it needs two:

```cpp
void drawPaged(void (*drawCallback)(const void*), const void* pv)
```

The first argument is the function pointer (or the one wrapped by `std::bind`!). The second argument seems to be some data that will be passed on to that function. (according to the [linked API)

The error actually explains it, it suspects that you are trying to call `void GxEPD2_BW::drawPaged(void ()(const void), const void*)`. Hence it mentions this as a candidate.

What you need to do is something like this:

```cpp
display.drawPaged(std::bind(&MyClass::drawClassCallback, this, std::placeholders::_1), &var);
```

`std::placeholders::_1` is the placeholder that represents the `var` argument that will be passed on when it is called.